# List of elements joined by OR condition

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation, logic

A simple command

```
Or[f[1], f[2], f[3]]
```

gives

`f[1] || f[2] || f[3]`

How this can be done automatically?

I try

```
Or[Table[f[i], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

and similar, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `Or@@Table[f[i], {i, 1, 3}]` or `Array[f, {3}, 1, Or]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Or @@ Table[f@i, {i, 3}]
```

> f[1] || f[2] || f[3]

Also

```
Or@@f/@Range@3
Array[f, {3}, 1, Or]
```